# How can I filter posts rendered to a user based on that user's location in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-models, geodjango

I'm building a Django social networking site, so I basically want to show posts in news feed in a way like if someone is in New York, he should get posts from fellow network users and possibly nearby places. How can I achieve this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the GIS QuerySet documentation pages in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/

If you have latitudes & longitudes stored as a geometry field, you can use `dwithin` to filter users within a certain distance:

> **within:**
> Returns models where the distance to the geometry field from the
> lookup geometry are within the given distance from one another. Note
> that you can only provide Distance objects if the targeted geometries
> are in a projected system. For geographic geometries, you should use
> units of the geometry field (e.g. degrees for WGS84) .

> Example:
> `Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__dwithin=(geom, D(m=5)))`